# Как правильно реализовать класс содержащий коллекции объектов?

Tags: c++, ооп

Надо реализовать класс содержащий коллекции объектов. Мне надо чтоб там был функционал добавления объектов, удаления, вывода на экран, поиск по параметру (по коду). Но не понимаю как правильно это спроектировать.

```
class Registry {
 
private:
 
    vector<Patient> patients;
    vector<Doctor> doctors;
    vector<Appointment> appointments;
 
public:
 
    Registry();
 
    ~Registry();
 
    const vector<Patient> &GetPatients() const;
 
    const vector<Doctor> &GetDoctors() const;
 
    const vector<Appointment> &GetAppointments() const;
 
    void SetPatients(vector<Patient> patients);
 
    void SetDoctors(vector<Doctor> doctors);
 
    void SetAppointments(vector<Appointment> appointments);
 
    void AddDoctor(string name, string surname, string qualification);
 
    void RemoveDoctor(vector<Doctor>::const_iterator itDoctor);
 
    void AddPatient(string name, string surname, string phone, int age);
 
    void RemovePatient(vector<Patient>::const_iterator itPatient);
 
    void AddAppointment(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, vector<Patient>::const_iterator itPatient,
                        vector<Doctor>::const_iterator itDoctor);
 
    void RemoveAppointment(vector<Appointment>::const_iterator itAppointment);
 
    void ShowAll(const vector<Patient> &patientsVector);
 
    void ShowAll(const vector<Doctor> &doctorsVector);
 
    void ShowAll(const vector<Appointment> &appointmentsVector, const vector<Patient> &patientsVector,
                 const vector<Doctor> &doctorsVector);
 
    vector<Patient>::const_iterator FindByCode(const vector<Patient> &patientsVector, int code);
 
    vector<Doctor>::const_iterator FindByCode(const vector<Doctor> &doctorsVector, int code);
 
    vector<Appointment>::const_iterator FindByCode(const vector<Appointment> &appointmentsVector, int code);
 
};
```

Я думаю, что у меня плохо то, что например методы RemovePatient, RemoveDoctor и т.д не перегруженные, было бы наверно лучше сделать чтобы это был один перегруженный метод Remove. Но как мне это сделать если я в геттере возвращаю константную ссылку, и не могу потом ее менять. А если я буду возвращать просто по значению, то тогда мне надо будет брать через геттер этот вектор, удалять из него что мне надо методом Remove, и потом сеттером устанавливать в объект измененный вектор? Что-то я уже совсем запутался..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мысли вслух:
Не совсем понятно зачем вы в методы класса передаете ссылки на поля класса?
А геттеры нужны только для того, чтобы иметь доступ к данным объекта за пределами класса.
Также, хранить итераторы на `Patient` и `Doctor` в векторе `Appointment` - не самая здравая мысль. А если вы удалили доктора, а потом добавили нового? В итоге у вас операцию на глазах будет делать проктолог.
У пациентов и докторов должен быть какой-то уникальный идентификатор, по которому их искать и их же добавлять в `Appointment`. И это точно не итератор из вектора, т.к. итератор - это идентификатор места хранения объекта, а не самого объекта. Например можно в классах `Patient` и `Doctor` сделать статический счетчик. Или использовать хэш-функцию.
Если у вас класс Реестр, то он должен только хранить объекты. Объекты должны создаваться при помощи своих классов `Patient` и `Doctor`. Ну или написать фабричные функции.
`Add()` по идее должен принимать объект (ссылку) класса. Т.е. вы где-то создаете объект нужного класса, а потом добавляете его в регистр. Так же, как `std::vector<>` - он принимает объект класса и кладет его в нужную ячейку.

```
Add( Doctor& a){}
Add( Patient& a){}
Add( Appointment& a){}
```

`Remove()` также принимает либо ссылку на объект, который нужно удалить, либо ID.
Константные ссылки на вектора нужно возвращать только в случае, если вы собрались работать с ними за пределами класса - что не совсем правильно.

```
class Registry {
 
private:
 
    vector<Patient> patients;
    vector<Doctor> doctors;
    vector<Appointment> appointments;
    
    // физически удаляют объект из вектора
    void Remove(vector<Doctor>::iterator itDoctor);
    void Remove(vector<Patient>::iterator itPatient);
    void Remove(vector<Appointment>::iterator itAppointment);

    // находят в векторе нужный объект по коду
    vector<Patient>::iterator FindPatient(int code);
    vector<Doctor>::iterator FindDoctor(int code);
    vector<Appointment>::iterator FindAppointment(int code);

public:
    void Add( Doctor& a);
    void Add( Patient& a);
    void Add( Appointment& a); 

    void ShowAllPatients(void);
    void ShowAllDoctors(void);
    void ShowAllAppointments(void);
};
```

Ещё можно немножко аля "метапрограммирование" сделать.  Например создать типы данных `DoctorID`, `PatientID`, `AppointmentID` (обертки) и на их основе перегружать методы.

```
struct DoctorID { int value; };
struct AppointmentID { int value; };
struct PatientID { int value; };

class Doctor
{
    DoctorID id;
    ....
};
class Registry 
{
    int Find(DoctorID id);
    int Find(PatientID id);
    int Find(AppointmentID id);
};
```

Comment: На самом деле в программе у объектов есть уникальные идентификаторы как вы описали, просто например в методе `AddAppointment` я передаю итератор, и потом в этом методе получаю id доктора и пациента обращаясь к итератору, а не сразу передаю id доктора в метод.

Comment: "Не совсем понятно зачем вы в методы класса передаете ссылки на поля класса?" - просто как мне по другому сделать перегрузку тех же методов ShowAll? Тогда у меня будет ShowAllPatients, ShowAllDoctors, ShowAllAppointments, и т.д.

Comment: А зачем такие сложности? Итератор имеет смысл передавать, когда нужен доступ к вектору. У методов класса и так есть доступ к векторам. Передавайте сразу ID.  Ну и пусть будут  `ShowAllPatients`, `ShowAllDoctors`, `ShowAllAppointments` - это же интерфейс. А чтобы избежать дублирования кода пусть они вызывают `private` метод с отображением `Show( identifier )`.

Comment: понял, спасибо. А что насчет методов Add, Remove, ShowAll и const ссылок

Comment: `Add()` по идее должен принимать объект (ссылку) класса. Т.е. вы где-то создаете объект нужного класса, а потом добавляете его в регистр. Так же, как `std::vector<>` - он принимает объект класса и кладет его в нужную ячейку. `Remove()` также принимает либо ссылку на объект, который нужно удалить, либо ID. Константные ссылки на вектора нужно возвращать только в случае, если вы собрались работать с ними за пределами класса - что не совсем правильно. Опять-таки константным будет вектор, но ничего не помешает при этом попасть внутрь конкретного объекта и что-то там поменять.

Comment: спасибо большое за ваши ответы, но вопрос: "Remove() также принимает либо ссылку на объект, который нужно удалить, либо ID." Почему он не может принимать итератор? Ведь тот же метод `erase()` у вектора принимает итератор на элемент который надо удалить.

Comment: Потому что у вас класс более высокоуровневый. Вы можете создать `private` метод удаления с итератором. И вызывать его из вашего метода. А так у вас итераторы нигде не хранятся (не должны) - это служебная внутренняя информация в классе. И получить итератор на входе, условно от человека, который пользуется вашим регистром, не получится. Т.е. вы получаете информацию об объекте, ищете его в векторе - получаете итератор, удаляете по итератору. Но вот в этом процессе, удаление по итератору, не должно быть видно снаружи класса.

Comment: а вот у меня же есть метод `FindByCode` который ищет по коду пациента или доктора и возвращает итератор, то что, мне его переделать чтоб он возвращал ссылку на объект?

Comment: Наверное этот метод лучше сделать `private`. Тогда `Remove()` принимает идентификатор, вызывает внутри себя `iterator FindByCode()` и если объект найден, вызывает служебный `Remove(iterator it)`. Т.е. никто не говорит, что итераторами нельзя пользоваться. Можно и нужно - в служебных целях. Их нельзя хранить в качестве долговременного идентификатора объекта, т.к. при изменении вектора итераторы могут могут стать невалидными.

Comment: А если например в `Remove()` передали какой-то неправильный код пациента, и `iterator FindByCode()` не нашел пациента с таким кодом. Тогда сделать чтоб он возвращал, например какой то enum с кодами ошибок?

Comment: Обычно если элемент не найден, возвращается `iterator end()`

Comment: "Тогда `Remove()` принимает идентификатор, вызывает внутри себя `iterator FindByCode()` и если объект найден, вызывает служебный `Remove(iterator it)`" А если объект не найден, тогда же `Remove()` тоже должен что-то вернуть?

Comment: По вашему желанию. Можно вернуть код ошибки, можно выкинуть исключение, а можно ничего не делать. Ваша программа - ваша логика.